# Parsing srtructure file Python

Tags: python, parsing, if-statement, case-when

I want to understand the peculiarity of using the construction Case When in Python.
I have a text file of the following kind:

```
Head 1
a 10
a 14
a 15
Head 4
a 32
a 55
a 79
Head 53
a 22
a 33
Head 33
a 11
a 66
Head 32
a 88
a 89
a 88
End
```

I want parse and structure this file to next plane:

```
Head 1, a 10
Head 1, a 14
Head 1, a 15
Head 4, a 32
Head 4, a 55
Head 4, a 79
Head 53, a 22
Head 53, a 33
Head 33, a 11
Head 33, a 66
Head 32, a 88
Head 32, a 89
Head 32, a 88
```

The first thing I learned when I started to learn Python this is the absence of the case when.

The way that I try:

```
array = []
with open('C:/file/1.txt') as f:
 for line in f:
  if line[0:4] == 'Head':
   Header = line
   print(Header)
  elif line[0:1] == 'a':
   Subheader = line
   print(Subheader)
  else:
   continue
```

Is it possible to decompose the data in the required format using this approach?
Thanks

Comment: Why not try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file is named `filename.txt`:

```
>>> with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
...     current_head = None
...     result = []
...     for line in f:
...         if line.startswith('End'):
...             break
...         elif line.startswith('Head'):
...             current_head = line.rstrip()
...         else:
...             result.append('{}, {}'.format(current_head, line.rstrip()))
... 
>>> for line in result:
...     print(line)
... 
Head 1, a 10
Head 1, a 14
Head 1, a 15
Head 4, a 32
Head 4, a 55
Head 4, a 79
Head 53, a 22
Head 53, a 33
Head 33, a 11
Head 33, a 66
Head 32, a 88
Head 32, a 89
Head 32, a 88
```

Comment: I just wrote an almost identical solution, you beat me by a couple of seconds.  Just a quick suggestion:  I would make this a generator, and just yield the `''{}, {}.format` result instead of building a list.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You can't return something that isn't in a function

Comment: @Misha1991 Thanks, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
data = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')][:-1]
s = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[0] == 'Head')]
new_s = [s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
final_s = [[i[0]+b for b in i[1:]] for i in new_s]
with open('filename1.txt', 'a') as f:
  for row in final_s:
    for i in row:
      f.write('{} {}, {} {}\n'.format(*i))
```

Output:

```
Head 1, a 10
Head 1, a 14
Head 1, a 15
Head 4, a 32
Head 4, a 55
Head 4, a 79
Head 53, a 22
Head 53, a 33
Head 33, a 11
Head 33, a 66
Head 32, a 88
Head 32, a 89
Head 32, a 88
```

Comment: I wasn't looking that the question, the answer provides me with a trick I will use ... :-)

Comment: This is the first line of the output of this solution: `['Head', '1'] ['a', '10'] ['a', '14'] ['a', '15']`

Comment: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: Many Thanks. I noticed that in this decision something went wrong after this line: new_s = [s[i]+s[i+1] for i in range(len(s)-1)]

Comment: You've made this way more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce No, and actually, there is no index error as it runs perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I just checked it again, same error. This code doesn't even work and is way over-complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: @Ajax1234 This is the first line of your new "solution". `Head 1 a 10Head 1 a 14Head 1 a 15Head 4 a 32Head 4 a 55Head 4 a 79Head 53 a 22Head 53 a 33Head 33 a 11Head 33 a 66Head 32 a 88Head 32 a 89Head 32 a 88Head 1 a 10`

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce How can that possibly be the output? My current code adds a comma between `Head \d` and `a`.

Comment: @Ajax1234 You don't really do much testing do you? Using `a` for the mode appends to the same file over and over. I just copy/paste your code and run it each time. Instead of creating a new file with `w`, you append to the previous file each time with `a`.